# Failure during cypress open after cypress v8.4.0 upgrade

Tags: automation, cypress

I'm trying to use cypress 8.4.0. Used  'npm install cypress --save-dev' to install it. However, after installation, running any command
npx cypress open/ run end up with error.

```
It looks like this is your first time using Cypress: 8.4.0

Cypress failed to start.
This may be due to a missing library or dependency. https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies
Please refer to the error below for more details.
----------
Command failed with exit code 2147483651: C:\Users\NEX20UR\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.4.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=672
----------
```

When I run 'npx cypress verify', I got below error:

```
Cypress verification timed out.
This command failed with the following output:
C:\Users\NEX20UR\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.4.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=466
----------
Command timed out after 30000 milliseconds: C:\Users\NEX20UR\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.4.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=466
Timed out
```

more details:
Cypress package version: 8.4.0
Cypress binary version: 8.4.0
Electron version: 13.2.0
Bundled Node version:
14.16.0

PS: I uninstalled and installed many times.

Answer (score 4):

Remove cache from location mentioned below:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Cypress

then reinstall cypress

npm install --save-dev cypress@8.4.0 -force,

Comment: Worked for me as well! I just had to delete the entire Cypress folder then reinstall the package.

Answer (score 0):

I future if u have issues with the latest cypress version downgrade to a stable lower version for eg

```
npm install --save-dev cypress@12.1.0
```

Also ,check if the npm is installed properly by opening command prompt and type

```
npm -v
```